# Is it possible to restore the db with incomplete datas?

Tags: postgresql, pg

I have a database(Postgres) backup which contains 100+ tables and most of them have many rows(100K) in it. But when I restored the db with the backup file(production data:- contains large volume of data) one table restored with less data nearly 300K rows are missing. Is there any possibility to happen like this or I'm missing anything?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There will be error messages in the logs or the console

Answer (score -2):

one option could be the following. You should store your data directory from the old db in a zip file and try again. More description [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup-file.html)

Michael